# Чем отличаются друг от друга отрицательный ноль и положительный ноль?

Tags: java, типы-данных

> Значения с плавающей точкой упорядочиваемы. В порядке от наименьшего к наибольшему идут отрицательная бесконечность, отрицательные конечные ненулевые значения, **отрицательный и положительный нули**, положительные конечные ненулевые значения и положительная бесконечность.

Чем отличаются друг от друга отрицательный ноль и положительный ноль? Понятно, что знаком, но ведь ноль есть ноль. В чем проявляется необходимость такого использования нуля?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Значения чисел с плавающей точкой, согласно [стандарту](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html), кодируются следующим образом:

```
знак (1 бит) | экспонента (8 бит) | дробная часть (23 бита)
```

Если мы захотим представить `0` в этом формате, то экспоненту и дробную часть мы "забьем" нулями. Но ведь еще остается знак! Вот и получается, что нуля два -- один отрицательный (ведущий бит равен 1) и один положительный (ведущий бит равен 0).

В арифметических операциях они ведут себя одинаково (кроме деления). Наличие плюса и минуса обусловлено спецификой хранения.

Comment: `1/-0 == -INF`, `1/+0 == +INF`, ЕМНИП. http://ideone.com/lyr0Rc

Comment: @VladD да, точно.

Answer (score 14):

Положительный и отрицательный ноль отличаются одним единственным битом (старшим битом двоичного представления чисел). Их необходимость диктуется разными соображениями. Вот некоторые из них (цитирую по сайту [ECA](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/computer-representation/)):

> Положительные и отрицательные нули имеют довольно важное значение. Вспомните математический анализ. Если интерпретировать 0 как предел некоторой последовательности, то с помощью знака нуля мы отражаем то, с какой стороны мы подошли к этому пределу. Таким образом, отрицательный ноль можно интерпретировать как то, что в процессе расчётов мы получили некое очень маленькое отрицательное число, и оно было округлено до нуля. ...

и далее

> ... если, например, в каких-то сложных вычислениях знаменатель дроби округлился до нуля, то благодаря тому, что этот ноль сохранит свой знак вы получите в ответе бесконечность с правильным знаком. От наличия правильного знака в ответе может зависеть выполнение или не выполнение некоего важного условия в программе. Таким образом, наличие знаковых нулей и бесконечности сильно упрощает логику некоторых сложных научных расчётов.